# Intersecting family of sets with empty intersection

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a family of subsets of $[n]$. Suppose that $\cap_{F\in\mathscr{F}}=\emptyset$ and for every $i\neq j$, $F_i\cap F_j\neq\emptyset$. Is it true that there exists 3 sets, $F_1, F_2, F_3\in \mathscr{F}$ such that there exists $v_1\in F_1\cap F_2$, $v_2\in F_2\cap F_3,$ and $v_3\in F_1\cap F_3$ with the $v_i$ not contained in any of the other intersections?

I am having a hard time finding a counter example, but the proof is avoiding me.

Comment: Hint: Consider the edges of a triangle.

Comment: Are you proposing this as a counter example? Or showing that it can be done? In this case, the 3 vertices of the triangle satisfy my conditions on $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$.

Comment: I can propose a counterexample using infinite sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you cannot find three such sets as you request. It means that, for every three $A,B,C\in\mathscr{F}$, you have that $A\cap B\subseteq C$ or $A\cap C\subseteq B$ or $B\cap C\subseteq A$; therefore $A\cap B\cap C$ coincides with $A\cap B$ or $A\cap C$ or $B\cap C$.

In any case, you can always reduce an intersection of three set to an intersection of two sets.

Start from 
$$\emptyset=F_1\cap\ldots\cap F_m$$
(where you suppose $\mathscr{F}=\{F_1,\ldots, F_m\}$) and use the remark above inductively to reduce the number of elements of the intersection to $2$.
You will end up with $F_i\cap F_j=\emptyset$, which is absurd.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Btw, the argument breaks in case of an infinite family, as hinted by the fact that hardmath (in a comment above) said to be able to produce a counterexample in that case.